# IIS 10 .Net Authorization woes with AD groups

Tags: iis, active-directory, authorization

I'm trying to secure a simple ASP.net website hosted on an internal IIS10 instance so that only a specific AD group can access it.

All my testing (and the final usage) would be internal to the same domain on which the IIS server resides - no external or cross-domain usage will occur.

Within Site Authentication I only have Windows Authentication enabled with a HTTP 401 Challenge response type.  Enabled providers are Negotiate and NTLM (in that order), Extended Protection is Off and Kernel-mode authentication is enabled

In .NET Authorisation Rules I have no explicit Deny Rules.

If I add a 'Specified users' Allow Rule for my user account (and thus the user for which I'm testing access to the website) then I am able to access the website.  At this point the relevant area of the web.config file looks like this:

```
<authorization>
<allow users="MYDOMAIN\MYUSERACCOUNT" />
</authorization>
```

If I remove that Allow Rule and add a 'Specified roles or user groups' Allow Row for an AD group for which my user account is a member of  then I am unable to access the website and browsing to it prompts me for a Sign in dialog box which entering my AD credentials then gives a 401 error.

At this point the relevant area of the web.config file looks like this:

```
<authorization>
<allow roles="MYDOMAIN\AwesomeUsers" />
</authorization>
```

I've tried changing various Authentication settings (changing the order, disabling Kernel-mode authentication etc), adding the domain groups in the 'allow users' section in the Web.config but I just cant get AD group authentication working.

IIS isn't my strong point so would really appreciate any hints or tips I can try, Thanks! :)

Comment: First thing to check is if Windows authentication is actually working properly. Is the value of `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name` your username?

Answer (score 0):

try to use below code:

web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="DOMAIN\ADGROUP" />
      <deny users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

applicationHost.config:

```
<configuration>
  <location path="YOUR-APP">
    <system.webServer>
      <security>
        <authentication>
          <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
          <windowsAuthentication enabled="true" />
        </authentication>
      </security>
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```